# Current CPU speed less than minimum?

Tags: cpu, cpu-frequency

My current CPU speed is (1253.029MHZ) less than the minimum (1400MHZ)? It's a new computer, is there something wrong with it?

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      23
Model:                           24
Model name:                      AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics
Stepping:                        1
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         1253.029
CPU max MHz:                     3600,0000
CPU min MHz:                     1400,0000
BogoMIPS:                        7186.89
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
L3 cache:                        4 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full AMD retpoline, IBPB conditiona
                                 l, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse s
                                 se2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtsc
                                 p lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpu
                                 id extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor
                                  ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes 
                                 xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm ex
                                 tapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowpre
                                 fetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core 
                                 perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_psta
                                 te sme ssbd sev ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2
                                  smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xs
                                 aveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsav
                                 eerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_sca
                                 le vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefi
                                 lter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif over
                                 flow_recov succor smca
```

Comment: Mine reports minimum of 500MHz but can't go below 800MHz. I just assumed that the hardware reports the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

If there is something wrong can't be judged by the output of lscpu. I've never seen the current frequency to be much lower than minimum frequency but considering how complex CPU's are it is not a surprise either. The Power Governor can through ACPI States either increase for extra performance or decrease or throttle the clock to reduce power and heat for each CPU core individually. It can also insert STOPCLOCK's where CPU's can skip heartbeats. AMD has Cool'n'Quiet and PowerNow! that can affect voltage and frequencies. The motherboard has an influence and maybe even the powersupply. But especially look at the temperatures of the CPU cores.

Linux exposes details about the frequencies through the /sys interface. lscpu uses these for it's summerization. But look at the kernel parameters directly if you suspect you have issue, especially when the system is under load.

> find /sys -name *freq*

The Kernel description on cpu frequency is documented here
[Linux Kernel CPUFREQ](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/cpufreq.html)